# Referring to the caption of current item in a For Next loop

Tags: vba

Self-taught VBA newbie here. I'm working on a userform where the user will be able to select checkboxes, and the captions of those checkboxes need to be compiled into a single cell (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIL3H.png)). Previously, I just had an If statement for every check box on the form (all 13 of them), but it's getting pretty unwieldy and I'm trying to clean it up.

So far, I've got a For Next loop that runs through all form controls to look for checkboxes and see if they're checked. <strike>Next I want to refer to the caption of the current `ctrl` in the loop, but there is no `ctrl.Caption` property. I tried to get around this by populating the variable `currentcb` with the current `ctrl`'s name, but the phrase `currentcb.Caption` is also returning an Invalid Qualifier error.</strike>

**UPDATE:** I changed around the code a little - @YowE3K was right that `ctrl.Caption` is a valid property, but now I get Run Time Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error. The debugger highlights the line that starts with `ws.Cells(lrow, 7).Value`. Any ideas? New code updated below.

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            ws.Cells(lrow, 7).Value = ws.Cells(lrow, 7) & vbCrLf & "|" & ctrl.Caption   'error thrown here
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Is there any workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

@YowE3K was right - ctrl.Caption does exist. Error 1004 was just from some of the hoop-jumping I did in the debugging process. Final, cleaned-up code below:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            ws.Cells(lrow, 7).Value = ws.Cells(lrow, 7) & vbCrLf & "|" & ctrl.Caption
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```